# MIPS: menu selection not working.

Tags: mips

Having a little problem with this code, it qtspim it says I am trying to compare the letters that will be read in with the syscall to those functions, i am comparing the string h to $v0 because if it is equal then it will go to function for that letter

`Instruction references undefined symbol at 0x004000dc
  [0x004000dc] 0x10220000  beq $1, $2, 0 [menu-0x004000d8]`

```
    la $a0, menu1
syscall                             #print menu1

la $a0, menu2
syscall                             #print menu2

la $a0, menu3
syscall                             #print menu3

la $a0, menu4
syscall                             #print menu4

la $a0, menu5
syscall                             #print menu5

la $a0, menu6
syscall                             #print menu6

la $a0, menu7
syscall                             #print menu7

la $a0, menu8
syscall                             #print menu8

la $a0, menu9
syscall                             #print menu9

la $a1, mselc                       #print mselc
syscall 

li $v0, 8
syscall 

j select                            #jump to select function

select:
beq $v0, 'h', menu                  
beq $v0, 'a', speed_add
beq $v0, 'd', speed_sub
beq $v0, 'p', passenger_add
beq $v0, 'r', passenger_remove
beq $v0, 'w', wiper
beq $v0, 'i', headlight_in
beq $v0, 'd', headlight_de
beq $v0, 't', turn1
j main
```

Answer (score 0):

`beq` expects to be comparing two registers, not a register and a value. You can read a character in, load a possible match into a second register, and then run `beq`, as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369735/mips-how-can-you-compare-a-character-taken-from-input).

Supposing you've captured a character into $v0, you could run a comparison something like this:

```
li $t0, 104 #'h'
beq $t0, $v0, menu
```

You can run each comparison in more or less the same way.

One other thing I notice: your input syscall is using opcode `8`, but [this page](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node8.html) says that's to read in a string. Should you be using opcode `12` to read in a single character?

Comment: would it look something like this then